# Can't change scrollbar color in a GTK3 theme without messing with it

Tags: firefox, themes, colors, gtk3, css

I use [GoldBars](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1265930/) as my GTK3 theme.
Differently from the screenshots, at least for Firefox 89, the vanilla, gray scrollbar is displayed, although other elements of the theme are clearly in effect.

I would like to color the scrollbar's trough. Something that works on other themes is to put this in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
.scrollbar.trough,
scrollbar trough {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But for this particular theme it does not work. I could track it down to this fragment of its `gtk-3.20/gtk-widgets.css` file:

```
window,
window.popup,
.background {
    background-color: @theme_bg_color;
    color: @theme_fg_color;
}
```

If I remove the `background-color` statement, the scrollbar gets the right color, but other parts of the window, such as the toolbar, lose their theming.

How can I color the scrollbar without affecting other parts of the theme?